# How to count frequency of pair words keeping the order sequence in text using R?

Tags: r, text, text-mining, word-frequency

So I've working on a way that I can get the frequency of pair words that happen in a sequence of events separated by a character. Example:

```
 Input:
 "Start>Press1>Press2>PressQR>Exit"
 "Start>PressA>Press2>PressQR>QuitL>Exit"
 "Start>Press1>Press2>Press3>Exit"`

 Output:
 Start>Press1    2
 Press1>Press2   2
 Press2>PressQR  2
 PressQR>Exit    1
 Start>PressA    1
 PressA>Press2   2
 Press2>PressQR  1
 PressQR>QuitL   1
 QuitL>Exit      1
 Press2>Press3   1
 Press3>Exit     1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a directed edgelist and then aggregate:

```
edgelist <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(x,">"), function(x) cbind(head(x,-1), x[-1]) ))
aggregate(count ~ ., data.frame(edgelist,count=1), FUN=sum)

#        X1      X2 count
#1   Press3    Exit     1
#2  PressQR    Exit     1
#3    QuitL    Exit     1
#4    Start  Press1     2
#5   Press1  Press2     2
#6   PressA  Press2     1
#7   Press2  Press3     1
#8    Start  PressA     1
#9   Press2 PressQR     2
#10 PressQR   QuitL     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input <- c("Start>Press1>Press2>PressQR>Exit","Start>PressA>Press2>PressQR>QuitL>Exit","Start>Press1>Press2>Press3>Exit")

gen_pairs <- function(x)
{
    x_split <- unlist(strsplit(x,">"))
    paste(x_split[-length(x_split)],x_split[-1],sep=">")
}
all_pairs <- unlist(lapply(input,gen_pairs))
all_pairs_ctab <- table(all_pairs)
as.data.frame(all_pairs_ctab[match(unique(all_pairs),names(all_pairs_ctab))])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tidytext package, which supports ngram tokenization through its `unnest_tokens` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

data.frame(text = c("Start>Press1>Press2>PressQR>Exit", "Start>PressA>Press2>PressQR>QuitL>Exit", "Start>Press1>Press2>Press3>Exit")) %>%     
    unnest_tokens(bigram, text, 'ngrams', n = 2, to_lower = FALSE) %>% 
    count(bigram)

#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>            bigram     n
#>             <chr> <int>
#> 1      Exit Start     2
#> 2   Press1 Press2     2
#> 3   Press2 Press3     1
#> 4  Press2 PressQR     2
#> 5     Press3 Exit     1
#> 6   PressA Press2     1
#> 7    PressQR Exit     1
#> 8   PressQR QuitL     1
#> 9      QuitL Exit     1
#> 10   Start Press1     2
#> 11   Start PressA     1
```

Or if you prefer, you could do the same thing with the underlying `tokenizers::tokenize_ngrams` function and `table`.